# Alternative idea to find minimum of $\sin^4x+\cos^4x$ without derivative

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

My question is about to find minimum value of $f(x)=\sin^4x+\cos^4x$ without derivation.

My trial is listed below
$$\sin^4x+\cos^4x=\\(\sin^2x+\cos^2x)^2-2\sin^2x\cos^2x=\\1-2(\frac{\sin^2(2x)}{2})^2\\\to min=\frac 12$$ and second try is to use cauchy schwarz inequality $$1.\sin^2x+1.\cos^2x\leq (\sin^4x+\cos^4x)(1^2+1^2)\\(\sin^4x+\cos^4x)\geq \frac12\\min=\frac 12$$ I am thankful if you show other Idea to solve this minimization.

Comment: In the third line, I think you mean $1-\frac{\sin^2(2x)}{2}.$

Comment: $ \ \sin^4 x \ + \ \cos^4 x \ = \ \frac34 + \frac14 \cos(4x) \ \ , $ which has the minimum $ \ \frac34  -  \frac14 \ \ . $

Comment: There's also AM-GM, $(\sin^4x+\tfrac14)+(\cos^4x+\tfrac14)\geqslant \sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$, with equality possible when $x=\tfrac{\pi}4$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $t = \sin^2x$, then $t\in[0,1]$ and

$$f(x) = (1-\sin^2x)^2+\sin^4x = (1-t)^2+t^2 = 2t^2-2t+1$$

This quadratic function has minimum at $t = {1\over 2}$ so...